# Windows Azure AD Sync Tool - Credentials of the supplied user do not map to a forest

Tags: sync, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, office365

I'm having problems with the Windows Azure Active Directory Sync Tool and Office 365.  We did have it set up correctly and was working for about 2 months.

Today, the VM it was running on destroyed itself and we had to restore from backup.  Running through the Sync tool configuration wizard, it asks for some domain credentials.  No matter what I enter (new accounts all the way up to the domain administrator), I just get the error:

> The credentials of the supplied user DOMAIN\user do not map to a forest.

We have tried reinstalling the Sync tool, and completely rebuilding the VM, but we always get this error.  Google had only one answer (flush DNS and re-register in DNS), but this has not worked.

Any one else run into this problem?

Comment: I have run into this same issue.  Any luck figuring out what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Stegzilla,

The answer to this question should be an easy one, but it can be tricky. In my experience with this tool as a Microsoft contractor, it seems that trying to reuse the registry of the old server (as in the backup you restored from) is not going to work. It corrupts the registry.

The only way to fix this issue is a fresh vm with the OS installed from a fresh ISO image and not a backup or a clone. Get a fresh download of the latest version of the tool from Exchange Online or Azure Active Directory under users > active users. It will be at the top of the page.

Doing this should help.